# Twitter Highlights on android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, twitter

Twitter recently introduced one new feautre like Highlights in android app, its really very cool and the same like i want to develop and implement in my app. Does anyone know any idea how we can do the same on Android app? Thanks.[image]